# Why does ls "~/Music/iTunes/iTunes Media/Audiobooks" fail?

Tags: bash

This is bash 3.2.  Why does

```
ls "~/Music/iTunes/iTunes Media/Audiobooks"
```

fail?

Shouldn't the quotes allow for the embedded space?

Edit: It fails with this error message:

> ls: ~/Music/iTunes/iTunes Media/Audiobooks: No such file or directory

Comment: Please update your question to indicate clearly *how* it fails (copy-and-paste the error message).

Comment: Also, check the [bash tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info) for useful preliminary debugging steps. [shellcheck](http://www.shellcheck.com) automatically points out the problem.

Comment: Keith: Error message added.

Comment: that other guy: Thanks for the tip on the bash tag wiki.  I didn't know about it.  I'm sure that I will also be grateful for your tip on shellcheck too when I figure out how to use the site.

Comment: that other guy: I think you wanted to point to this site: http://www.shellcheck.net/  Rather than the one you used.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The quotes do indeed ensure space is treated as part of the filename. However, they also prevent the `~` from expanding.

If you want to use `~`, put it outside the quotes:

```
ls ~/"Music/iTunes/iTunes Media/Audiobooks"
```

Otherwise, you can use `$HOME` inside double quotes:

```
ls "$HOME/Music/iTunes/iTunes Media/Audiobooks"
```

Comment: Thx Charles.  I should have figured that out.